# How can I refer to a computer in a domain using the NetBIOS name as is done with users? i.e. domain\computer like domain\user

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, netbios

I've tried researching this, but none of the documentation I've found states how this is done, or if it is possible.

I can refer to a domain user like so:

`domain\user`

Even when the domain is actually `ad.domain.com` because the NetBIOS name of the domain is just `domain` and that ultimately resolves to a Domain Controller for said domain which the user exists on as an Active Directory Object.

However, I can't find how to do the same for a computer. I realize users do not have NetBIOS names, so when I ask "How do I do this with a computer?" I'm really asking "How do I use two NetBIOS names in conjunction to refer to a computer?" which may not be possible.

Rather than referring to a computer as `computer.ad.domain.com`, I'd rather just do `domain\computer`, but none of my attempts to refer to a computer in this way resolve to that computer. The simplest form being in PowerShell:

`ping domain\computer`

When doing this, the Domain Controller responds, which makes sense:

`ping domain`

The computers in a Domain exist as Active Directory Objects, and when running these two scripts (?) in PowerShell, the returned attributes are mostly the same:

`Get-ADComputer -Filter *`
`Get-ADUser -Filter *`

So, I am uncertain why what I am attempting isn't working as expected.

Is there a more correct way to essentially use the shorthand for the domain when on a local network with its Domain Controllers when referring to computers rather than users? Or is this simply not possible?

Comment: In what context are you trying to refer to a computer this way? Ping uses name resolution, which even if you're using NetBIOS name resolution you would not be able to resolve "DOMAIN\COMPUTER", you would just be able to resolve "COMPUTER". When you use DOMAIN\USER you are specifying a **security context**, not a portion of a network. Windows Domains are not network objects.

Comment: The context was "for local network resolution" meaning I would use it when referring to computers in a different domain. Say I have `domain A` and `domain B` but both are part of the same Forest and in a trust relationship. Referring to a computer in `domain B` from a member of `domain A`, for example. But I believe the latter part of your comment is my answer. Those are not network objects, but security contexts.

Comment: For network resolution you either have to specify the FQDN and have an appropriate DNS server with DNS entries available, or you have to configure NetBIOS name resolution to specify just the NetBIOS computer name, or you have to use a hosts or lmhosts file.

Comment: Thanks. That answers my question then, or at least resolves it in that I realize now that I was coming at the problem from the wrong angle.